# Puppet Server not applying manifests

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, mcollective

I did a  Puppet/MCollective setup using four nodes.

```
  # mco ping
  Node-010.test.com                   time=107.58 ms
  Node-003.test.com                   time=110.68 ms
  Node-009.test.com                   time=114.42 ms
  Node-002.test.com                   time=116.49 ms
```

#mco puppet runonce  works fine but is not applying the manifests .

```
  # mco puppet runonce
  * [ ============================================================> ] 4 / 4
  Finished processing 4 / 4 hosts in 151.61 ms
```

My manifests configuration is as follows:

```
   # puppet master --configprint manifest
   /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests
```

My Site.pp is as follows

```
  # cat /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp
node default {
}
node 'Node-002.test.com'{
file {"/tmp/helloworld.txt":
      ensure => file,
      owner  => 'root',
      group  => 'root',
      mode   => '0644',
      content =>" Hi ",
   }
  }
```

Site.pp is not getting applied .

From the log file , it seems it is reading from cache and applying for nodes for which no rule exists .

```
  ` # tail -f /var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver/puppetserver.log
2016-06-21 20:21:06,355 INFO  [qtp1367105977-65] [puppet-server] Puppet    Compiled catalog for Node-009.test.com in environment qa in 0.04 seconds
2016-06-21 20:21:08,223 INFO  [qtp1367105977-65] [puppet-server] Puppet Caching node for Node-002.test.com
2016-06-21 20:21:08,618 INFO  [qtp1367105977-69] [puppet-server] Puppet Caching node for Node-002.test.com
```

Am i hitting some bug or missing some configuration item ?

Comment: Try to restart the puppetmaster and see if this helps...

Comment: Restarted puppetserver many a times but no help

Comment: The agent asked for the environment `qa`, whereas you showed `site.pp` of environment `production`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments: The agent asked for the environment `qa`, whereas you showed `site.pp` of the environment `production`. So, better double check the environments on both sides, master and agent. :)

Comment: How can I change environment from production to qa in puppet Server ?

Comment: @ZamaQues Depends on the version you're using. Normally, with recent / current versions, the puppetmaster will just serve the environment the agent asks for.

Comment: Thanks.  Versions are as follows
puppetserver-2.3.1 ,  puppet-agent-1.3.5

Comment: Verified it is serving from the environment the agent is asking. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @ZamaQues Glad to help, good luck!